Jupyter lab setting adjustment
My Jupyter lab shows hyper-parameter tuning in whole code in same page, I need to adjust the jupyter lab settings to get it into a box, like jupyter notebook. Here I have posted how is the outcome of both jupyter lab and Jupyter notebook Jupyter notebookJupyter Lab
I need to change the jupyter lab settings accordingly

Please read How do I ask a good question? thoroughly and use it as a guide in the future to post questions. And look at other related questions with good engagement.
